# Use REST API to initiate call to Twilio-registered SIP

Tags: php, rest, api, twilio, sip

I am trying to use REST API to initiate calls to a phone that I have SIP enabled through Obi/Twilio integration.  As I understand it, I've set up a user in my credentials list as ryan-1, and my SIP domain as "ggc".  Therefore my SIP U/N should be ryan-1@ggc.sip.twilio.com (or ggc.sip.us1.twilio.com).

When I try to initiate a call with the following code, it does not work.

```
$client->account->calls->create('Ryan', 'ryan-1@ggc.sip.us1.twilio.com', 'http://info.ggc.nyc/twilio/box/1.1.xml', array( 
    'Method' => 'GET',  
    'FallbackMethod' => 'GET',  
    'StatusCallbackMethod' => 'GET',    
    'Record' => 'false', 
));
```

This PHP page does not even load (500 error)

However, when I use the same code to call a phone it works fine.

```
$client->account->calls->create('+19173828964', '+13035061389', 'http://info.ggc.nyc/twilio/box/1.1.xml', array( 
    'Method' => 'GET',  
    'FallbackMethod' => 'GET',  
    'StatusCallbackMethod' => 'GET',    
    'Record' => 'false', 
));
```

What am I doing wrong?  From the [Twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/sip-making-calls), it seems like I just put the SIP address in the TO: place and a name in the FROM.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks to me like you have the arguments the wrong way around. The `to` parameter should come first. Additionally, when making calls to a SIP endpoint you should prepend `sip:` to the address.

Try this:

```
$client->account->calls->create('sip:ryan-1@ggc.sip.us1.twilio.com', 'Ryan', 'http://info.ggc.nyc/twilio/box/1.1.xml', array( 
    'Method' => 'GET',  
    'FallbackMethod' => 'GET',  
    'StatusCallbackMethod' => 'GET',    
    'Record' => 'false', 
));
```